# Basic for loop in java and data storage

Tags: java

I am very new to coding and I have a simple question. I want to input day, month and year inside a for loop and after inputting it I want to display all the inputted values on the same time. how to do it.kindly help me.
i have attached the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    int day = in.nextInt();
    String month = in.next();
    int year = in.nextInt();
}}

//need to display the entire content from the for loop
//suppose if the n value is 3 
//i will be giving 3 inputs
//10 jan 1998
//11 nov 2000
//12 dec 1995
//i want to print all at the same time
```

Kindly help me with it.

Comment: Save them in a list first, then print them all at the same time.

Comment: seperate list for all the 3 attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and you just want to print your inputs, just add the following to the loop:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d", day, month, year));
```

or otherwise, but not as pretty (at least in my opinion):

```
System.out.println(day + " " + day + " " + month + " " + year);
```

EDIT

As indicated, you want to print them all at the same time. To do so, you can just save them all in a list or an array for example like the following:
Before the loop:

```
String[] dates = new String[n];
```

In the loop:

```
dates[i] = String.format("%d %s %d", day, month, year);
```

And then go ahead and insert another loop to print the content of the array:

```
for(String date: dates){
   System.out.println(dates[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered, you are looking to set a number on how many dates you'd like the user to enter, take in that number of dates and then print out the dates after the user input.

Here is some basic code that will do that for you

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfInputs = 3;    //How many separate dates you would like to enter
    int day[] = new int[numOfInputs];   //declaring an integer array day and setting the array size to the value of numOfInputs
    String month[] = new String[numOfInputs];   //declaring a string array month and setting the array size to the value of numOfInputs
    int year[] = new int[numOfInputs];  //declaring an integer array year and setting the array size to the value of numOfInputs

    //get inputs
    for(int i=0;i<numOfInputs;i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a day");
        day[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a month");
        month[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a year");
        year[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    //print content
    for(int i=0;i<numOfInputs;i++) {
        System.out.println(day[i] + " " + month[i] + " " + year[i]);
    }
    //close scanner
    sc.close();
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question or if you need any clarification.

Comment: No problem, was this exactly what you were looking for?